# CPU usage pegged at 100% on windows vista

Tags: windows-vista, cpu-usage, task-manager

According to Task Manager the CPU Usage is 100% but when I click on the "Processes" and sort by CPU in descending order I see that the process using the most CPU is taskmgr.exe at 02%. All the others are at 00%. So what's eating up all my CPU cycles?

The CPU is a Intel Core 2 Solo CPU U3500 @ 1.40GHz. So it's not a spectacular CPU but still...  the behavior I'm seeing still doesn't make any sense.

Also, Aero is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, cannot yet comment. Windows update is know to sometimes cause 100% cpu usage. Click "show all processes" in taskmanager. If your notebook feels slow, see if svhost is at 100%, which would indicate Windows update is the fault. I think running it for a day or two fixed Windows update last time. If any other process is hang, try terminating it. If print spooler is at 100% restart the computer. If a virus is consuming all power, it may not show in the taskmanager.

Comment: Yah - svchost was at 100% and I was trying to download updates. That does sound like the most likely culprit. I'll let it run for a few days, as per your suggestion. /fingers crossed/

Comment: So this seems to have been the issue. I went ahead and disabled Automatic Updates on this computer. Maybe on a multi-core Windows Vista machine they might work better but not on a really out-of-date single-core machine. I also uninstalled Microsoft .NET. mscorsvw.exe was maxing the CPU out at 100% after the automatic updates were complete and for my purposes...  I don't need it.